# Latex macro that ignores (deletes or uncomments) certain text

Tags: macros, latex, environment

I hope there is a simple solution: I need a latex macro that ignores specific text from a tex-script. E.g.:

```
\begin{ignoretext}
bla bla
hello
\end{ignoretext}
```

Should compile to

```
hello
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is possible, but I assume your `hello` should be *outside* the `ignoretext` environment... correct?

Comment: No it is inside, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pythontex package

I achieved the result through the [`pythontex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) package. I'm assuming that you will search and install the compiler/package required for your system, in such a way you can run the following example.

This is a minimal example of what you are searching for:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\newcommand{\ignoretext}[2]{\pyc{%
  ret = r"#2".replace(r"#1", r'');%
  print(ret);%
}}

\begin{document}

\ignoretext{bla bla}{
bla bla 
Hello
}

\end{document}
```

This document (`test.tex`) must be compiled with:

```
pdflatex test.tex
pythontex test.tex
pdflatex test.tex
```

The result contains only

```
Hello
```

The macro works as follow:

1. First argument contains the text to remove
2. Second argument is your actual text

#### Comment package (bad answer)

It works with the [`comment`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package if you write your code in this way:

```tex
\begin{comment}
bla bla
\end{comment}
hello
```

it must be included in the preamble (`\usepackage{comment}`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Matteo (an also Werner). I fear I did not explain my problem well: I can only set the environment around the whole code (as I actually include the code). Then, a specific part should be commented out (here the "hello" part).

Comment: It is still not clear... how do you want to avoid to compile `bla bla`? based on position? based on actual text (all instances of `bla bla` should be commented)?

Comment: yeah, sorry :/ Based on actual text. Always remove the specific text "bla bla"

Comment: check the answer again